# GLM opengl clipping issues - Game Engine c++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, clipping, glm-math

I am currently working on my game-engine and I run into some troubles I can not figure out myself. I changed my mind about setting up my own math library so I went back to use GLM because it is a perfect solution.
But here comes the problem, with my Code everything worked well but now with the functions changed I get a problem with object clipping and intersection.

[Zoomed In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohrcn.png)

This first image shows how my scene looks when it is zoomed in. Everything looks almost perfect and the plane intersects the cube properly.

[Zoomed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNK9q.png)

Scrolling out the intersection gets randomly dissorted and I cannot explain what's happening nor do I have any clue where my problem is located.
This is the way I calculate my projection Matrix:

```
proj = glm::perspective((double)fovy, (double)aspect, (double)nearPlane,(double) farPlane);
```

and this is the way I calculate the view:

```
view = glm::lookAt(pos, tar, gameObject->transform.getUp());
```

I know I should poste more code but there is so much that I really don't know where to start. So please tell me which code could be of importance and I poste it. Thank you very much in advance and I hope somebody could help me. If more pictures are needed please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have enough depth resolution.  This happens when `nearPlane` is very small and `farPlane` is very large.  For example, 0.0001 to 10000.0 will give you low depth resolution.

Make `nearPlane` larger and `farPlane` smaller.

Comment: Wow thanks I tried this out before but I guess I had no luck in adjusting it properly. Thank you really much! I Set the values to 1.0f and 1000.0f now and it seems to work. Thank you!